# Calling a single method from a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a trivia game where there are multiple categories (like sports, history, art, etc.). At the end of each category's game, I want to show a scoreboard of results *only for that single* category.

By specifying the category in the method, I am now successfully filtering only for history scores, as seen here:

```
class ScoreboardController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @participations = Participation.where(finished: true, category: "history").order(score: :desc)  
   end
 end
```

While that is good, I now need to make it so that the scoreboard controller can produce a filtered set of scores for history, sports, and any other number of category iterations, whereas it only covers the history category at current.

To make this happen, I tried creating a second method within the controller for:

```
  @participations = Participation.where(finished: true, category: "sports").order(score: :desk)
```

Unfortunately, that still only returned scores from the first method for history with no sports scores.

I think I am doing one of two things wrong:

1) Am I writing the methods incorrectly by adding additional iterations into the same controller?

2) In the **scoreboard view** (as opposed to the scoreboard controller), I am not calling the controller correctly.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

**Additional Info: Scoreboard View**

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Score</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <% @participations.each_with_index do |participation, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td>#<%= index + 1 %></td>
      <td><%= participation.user.username %></td>
      <td><%= participation.category %></td>
      <td><%= participation.score %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please post your controller code, not just snippets

Comment: @Tim - That is the scoreboard controller code above. Are you asking for the participation model that it's referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your ScoreboardController index to contain different instance variables for different categories. ie:

**ScoreboardController.rb**

```
def index
    @participations_score = Participation.where(finished: true, category: "history").order(score: :desc) 
    @participations_history = Participation.where(finished: true, category: "sports").order(score: :desc) 
    # other particpation categories
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>History Scoreboard</h1>

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Score</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <% @participations_history.each do |participation_history| %>
    <tr>
      <td>#<%= participation_history.id %></td>
      <td><%= participation_history.username %></td>
      <td><%= participation_history.category %></td>
      <td><%= participation_history.score %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>

<!--- Add more code for the rest of the categories --->
```

I strongly suggest that you brush up on your knowledge of the Ruby programming language as well as the Ruby on Rails framework. You can do so by going to [Code academy](http://codeacademy.com/).

Comment: Changing the index seems like the easiest solution here. I tried this by creating the instance variable for participations_history to try it out, but it is returning an error: `undefined method each_ ` in the index.html file after using your code. Is there any additional magic needed to identify the instance in the scoreboard's html file?

Comment: @darkginger, I have changed the code to remove the syntax error. It should be `@participations_history.each` not `@participations_history.each_`

Comment: No problem. Good luck @darkginger!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), with a [`singular resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) for:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories do
   resource :scoreboard, module: :categories #-> url.com/categories/:category_id/scoreboard
end

#app/controllers/categories/scoreboards_controller.rb
class Categories::ScoreboardsController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @results = Participation.where(finished: true, category: params[;category_id]).order(score: :desc) 
    end
end
```

This will allow you to invoke the `scoreboards#show` action, populating with the appropriate `category` from the routes....

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @category = ...
      redirect_to [@category, :scoreboard]
   end
end
```

---

**Associations**

Now, there's a better way.

Instead of calling `Participation` naked, you'll be best using the `categories` and `scoreboards` association you *should* have set up in the backend:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations
   has_many :scoreboards, through: :participations
end

#app/models/participation.rb
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
   belongs_to :scoreboard
end

#app/models/scoreboard.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations
   has_many :categories, through: :participations
end
```

This will allow you to use the same routes as above, but this time populating the response through the associations:

```
#app/controllers/categories/scoreboards_controller.rb
class Categories::ScoreboardsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @category = Category.find params[:id]
        @results  = @category.participations.where(participation: {attribute: true})
    end
end
```